# Show few links using hyperlink in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm using hyperlink in gridview.

With `NavigateUrl` I can link my PDF documents from my project directory /pdf/ArchiveCode.pdf.

Right now I have two PDF documents in my directory (first document 020001.0001.0001.pdf and second document 100410.0001.0001.pdf), but in the hyperlink column from gridView are shown all links with text value 'PDF'.

```
----------------------------------------
|      PDF         | ArchiveCode       | - Headers from gridView
----------------------------------------
|              PDF | 020001.0001.0001  |
----------------------------------------
|              PDF | 100410.0001.0001  |
----------------------------------------
|              PDF | 020001.0131.0441  |
----------------------------------------
|              PDF | 020001.0005.0007  |
----------------------------------------
|              PDF | 020001.0003.0002  |
----------------------------------------
...
```

Because I have just two PDF documents is it possible to hide other links (dead links) that are not used from the gridview and to activate the link when I create new document in my project directory?

Here is the code for the `HyperLink` and for `ArchiveCode` column:

```html
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PDF">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="PDFHyperLink" Target="_blank" runat="server" Text="PDF"  NavigateUrl   = '<%# "~/pdf/" + Eval("ArchiveCode") + ".pdf" %>'>
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>        
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ArchiveCode">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblKod" Text='<%# Eval("ArchiveCode") %>' runat="server"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: You need to update your datasource to show only active / available files.

Comment: So you want to disable the links to non-existing documents, but still render the information about them in the `GridView` and once they exist in the directory, render them as links? I would suggest using another field in your `DataSource` which indicates the existence of your files. Once you have that, you can use an `if{}else{}` statement to render them conditionally.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I'll extend my DadaSource with one more Column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to your comments I finally fix my little problem and I can control the Hyperlink TEXT in GridView using simple bool condition. In my database table I add new boolean column with the name "activePDF". After that in my GridView I modify the asp:HyperLink:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="PDFHyperLink" Target="_blank" runat="server" NavigateUrl = '<%# "~/pdf/" + Eval("ArchiveCode") + ".pdf" %>'  Text ='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("activePDF"))== true? "PDF":"" %>'>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: I'd suggest binding the activePDF column to the Visible property instead of changing the text to "", this makes sure the link isn't rendered to the client (which slightly reduces load on server internet connection).